# How to save a PDF from a link that automatically starts to download?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape and SAVE pdf files that automatically start to download once you click on the URL, such as: https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/documents/downloadPublic?documentIds=080166e5b0a3b62d&appId=PPGMS

I have been trying with urllib but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the download is initiated by the javascript the most universal solution is to use a browser that actually executes the javascript.

Selenium driver with headless PhantomJS should do the trick in general case.

In this particular case (for this page that is) the code that executes the download is rather simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    window.location='https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/documents/downloadPublic/NXBvSk9oSlVwSFhueUcxNlJDUnNOSGVnOEpNWkVvWDlveDFoalRUb3E2VC8yVHlIU3hYMFVBPT0=/attachment/VFEyQTQ4M3ptUWNRa2R4dEZ6MkU3endWb2dWSDJHNTM=';
});
</script>
```

You can download the page first, parse the url starting with `window.location` and then download the file it points to (just make sure you include the cookies returned with the html page). This would be brittle as any change to the implementation of this page may break it.

Here's how this can be done with [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import re
import requests
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/documents/downloadPublic?documentIds=080166e5b0a3b62d&appId=PPGMS')
url_pattern = re.compile("window.location='(?P<url>.*)';")
html = response.text
match_result = url_pattern.search(html)
url = match_result.group('url')
content_response = s.get(url)
file_content = content_response.content
with open('/tmp/file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file_content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the question of how to save "the file it points to" still remains open.

Comment: That perfectly does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

for link in link_list:
    urlretrieve(link)
```

Comment: Firstly, you should not ask questions in the answer, comments to the question should be used for that. Secondly, `ulrretrieve` will not execute javascript that initiates the load.

Comment: Hi, I believe this just saves the html but not the actual attachment (pdf file). Please correct me if I'm wrong.